# Создание маршрута (REST API WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, rest

Хочу вывести меню **WordPress**'а, прописав к нему свой маршрут.

У меня есть следующий код в *functions.php*:

```
function get_menu() {
    return wp_get_nav_menu_items('header_menu');
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
            register_rest_route( 'routes', '/menu', array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'get_menu',
    ) );
} );
```

У меня URL получается следующим: http://uer/wp-json/routes/menu (на локальном сервере)

При переходе по этому маршруту мне выдаёт **false** вместо пунктов меню,
якобы оно не создано.

Оно как раз-таки есть, и потому я не понимаю в чём дело.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начало нужно получить локацию меню с помощью $locations = get_nav_menu_locations(); А потом уже использовать wp_get_nav_menu_items($locations['header_menu']);
Посмотри пример на странице: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_get_nav_menu_items